# I'm getting warning on LineRenderer SetWidth that it's obsolete how should i fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
lineRenderer.SetWidth(startWidth, endWidth);
lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(linePoints.Count);
```

On both lines same warning:

'LineRenderer.SetVertexCount(int)' is obsolete: 'SetVertexCount has been deprecated. Please use the numPositions property instead.'

And

'LineRenderer.SetWidth(float, float)' is obsolete: 'SetWidth has been deprecated. Please use the startWidth, endWidth, or widthCurve properties instead.'

I tried this then:

```
lineRenderer.startWidth(startWidth, endWidth);
```

But then getting error on startWidth property:

'LineRenderer.startWidth' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Reading the documentation is a reflex that too few people have.... https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the `LineRenderer` functions has been changed to properties and also renamed to avoid confusion. You set properties not call it as a function. For `lineRenderer.SetVertexCount`, you use `lineRenderer.positionCount` to set that.

```
lineRenderer.startWidth = startWidth;
lineRenderer.endWidth = endWidth;
lineRenderer.positionCount = linePoints.Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do what the compiler is suggesting.

I.E.:

```
lineRenderer.startWidth = startWidth;
lineRenderer.endWidth = endWidth;
lineRenderer.positionCount = linePoints.Count;
```