# Why the property SetVertexCount is not exist in LineRenderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class DrawRectangle : MonoBehaviour
{
    LineRenderer line;
    void Start()
    {
        line = transform.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.SetVertexCount(5);
        line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(-1, 1, 0));
        line.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
        line.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(1, -1, 0));
        line.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(-1, -1, 0));
        line.SetPosition(4, new Vector3(-1, 1, 0));
    }
}
```

The script is attached to a GameObject with LineRenderer component.
But I'm getting errors on all the line properties.
The SetVertexCount and all the SetPosition do not exist.

I'm using unity ver 5.5.1f1 Personal

Comment: Try setting positionCount on the lineRenderer. I think the interface for LineRenderer has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting warning on LineRenderer SetWidth that it's obsolete how should i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442631/im-getting-warning-on-linerenderer-setwidth-that-its-obsolete-how-should-i-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just answered some hours before you posted this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44442707/1895303

Use lineRenderer.positionCount.

```
lineRenderer.positionCount = 5;
```